# Header elements alignment

Tags: css, menu, alignment, css-transitions

I'm trying to replicate this header:
https://minelligroup.com/
on this website that is related:
https://blog.minelligroup.com/packaging

But, as you can see, I have some alignment problem with the social sharing buttons.
I can't find what is impeding them to be aligned with the rest of the menu bar.
I suppose it could be a problem of transition but I can't solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine the nav like so

[image: Navbar breakdown]

There are two columns, in the second column are the socials and menu. Each are 100% in width relative to their parent column. Use `text-align:right;` and `display:inline-block;` to "float" them right.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5fdpwngy/

Comment: Uhm, this is not exactly what I need. I need the social icons to be on the right of the menu, not on top of it.

Comment: This is replicated from what it looks like on mine. This what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/24fj0zsa/

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Which browser are you using to see it like your first example?

Comment: Firefox on 1920x1080

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at it on Firefox and I can see the problem!
Regarding your advice about the menu, i can see your advice is to float the div you called "parents" on the left. In this case the menu transition will change and the menu item will be shifted on the left.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me, do you still have a problem putting it together?

Comment: Yes. If I use your advice the transition of the menu changes and this doesn't have to happen.